# How to run multiple instances of Activiti in different ports?

Tags: java, maven, activiti

I have the pom.xml file which sets the tomcat port to 8080 in my activiti project.

```
<maven.tomcat.port>8080</maven.tomcat.port>
```

Is there a way I can set multiple ports in pom.xml?

Comment: are you using tomcat to deploy war file ?

Comment: @MohammadRezaAlagheband yes

Answer (score 0):

are you using spring boot? Why do you need more ports? 
If you want to have multiple instances you will need multiple tomcats in different java processes. But you usually don’t need that, if you provide more information, we can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: Yes, I use springboot. I want to run two instances of activiti for testing purposes.

Comment: So just two spring boot apps with different server.port in the application proerties file

Answer (score 0):

> For having two instances of activity you don't need to run it on two
>   different port instead you can duplicate WAR files and rename as described in approach 1 :

## First Approach

1. For v6.0.0, you can just download the activiti-6.0.0.zip, extract it.
2. Copy `activiti-rest` WAR file and rename one of them as `activiti-rest1` and the other as `activiti-rest2`
3. Copy `activiti-app` WAR file and rename one of them as `activiti-app1` and the other as `activiti-app2`
4. Move all 4 WAR file into your tomcat webapp
5. Start Tomcat

Now you can access them in the following pattern:

> - http://localhost:8080/activiti-app1
> - http://localhost:8080/activiti-app2
> - http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest1
> - http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest2

---

## Second Approach

If this still does not satisfy your needs, make sure you have two instances of tomcat available in your machine

1. Copy war files into the both tomcat instances
2. Start 1st Tomcat instance by default configuration (so by default port 8080)
3. Go to the path for the 2nd Tomcat instance and edit `Tomcat2/conf/server.xml`
4. Find the following code :

   ```
      <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
          maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
          enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
          connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
   ```
5. Change the connector port from default 8080 to another valid port number like **9090**.
6. Start tomcat instance 2

Now you can access them in the following pattern:

> - http://localhost:8080/activiti-app
> - http://localhost:9090/activiti-app
> - http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest
> - http://localhost:9090/activiti-rest

---

## Third Approach

If you are using Activiti by its maven dependency inside your spring-boot application then copy your code to another place and edit `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources` then change port as   `server.port=9090` .